# wp_remote_request and cURL doesn't working

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, curl, localhost

I made a program that is running on 'SAM local start-api' command that starts a server on 127.0.0.1:3000

I'm developing a plugin for woocommerce that needs to make a request to this server.

I'm trying to use the wp_remote_request that returns the following:

```php
    object(WP_Error)#1602 (2) {   ["errors"]=>   array(1) {
        ["http_request_failed"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(74) "cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused"
        }   }   ["error_data"]=>   array(0) {   } }
```

and with cURL returns 1...

the code:

```php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/'
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    curl_close($curl);
    wp_die(print_r($response));

    // wp_die( var_dump( $url ) );

    $resposta = wp_remote_request( 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/', [ 'method'=>'GET' ] );

    wp_die( var_dump( $resposta ) );
```

I'm using a Docker image to develop the plugin that is running on port 80.

The request is hooked in the following:

```php
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', [ $this, 'analisar_novo_pedido' ] );
```

and i setted the following:

```php
        add_filter( 'block_local_requests', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'https_local_ssl_verify', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'https_ssl_verify', '__return_false' );
```

thanks for helping...

Comment: _“Connection refused”_ usually means that you either don’t actually have any service listening on that port, or that there is a problem reaching the port. You said you used docker to develop this plugin - what about the rest of it, what you have running on port 3000, is that also within the docker container? If not, then you might need to figure out how to get connections to “the outside” from within your container first.

Comment: yes... it's outside the docker container... but, for example if I put http://google.com.br it works!!!